# Compiz and Clearlooks window border breaks active/inactive title bars

Tags: 11.04, compiz, emerald

When I turn on Compiz with the Compiz tray switcher and I use Clearlooks, Dust Sand, or  possibly any title bar style that normally has window icons on right, some window title bars will not change. Instead, they stay selected or unselected randomly. Some windows, like Ubuntu Software Center and CCSM are unaffected. This problem only happens with GTK window manager. I am using the Malteworld compiz ppa for Emerald.

The problem does not happen with plain Metacity, or a title bar style that normally has close button on right.

Edit: It still happens with Emerald. Reinstalled with upgrade option (yeah, 11.04 to 11.04) and still same problem. So maybe faulty package?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

No the problem is a faulty emerald, that is no longer maintained. I used to use emerald myself, but I have since stopped; reason being that emerald is no longer developed actively and is now unstable and buggy.

My suggestion would be that you return to using metacity for window decorations (gtk-window-decorator).

If needed, you can report a bug via:
`ubuntu-bug compiz`

Comment: no, I did a clean reinstall without emerald, installed some of my old apps (not emerald), and the problem has returned.

Comment: again, the problem only happens with compiz (confirmed), gtk+ themes with buttons on right (probably), and only certain windows, oddly (100% confirmed) I'm using GTK right now.

Comment: @jimbo1qaz you should report a bug.

Comment: how do i report a bug? I might do that, but I don't know which package it is. here are some of the packages: compiz control, stellarium, supertux, supertuxkart, alsa mixer, armagetron advanced, xpenguins + applet.